# Clone with full path to repo

Tags: git

git repos have a path that includes more than just the repo name.  I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically have git clone a repository and include the full path, which will help me categorize my projects.

For example, I'd like `git clone git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git` to clone to `./scrooloose/nerdcommenter/` instead of just `./nerdcommenter/`.

Is there a flag in `git clone` for this, or do I just have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git` repo reference , you can simply do:

```
$ mkdir -p scrooloose/nerdcommenter
$ git clone git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git scrooloose/nerdcommenter
```

which can easily be scripted if that really needed.

There's no much benefit for having such logic in git as you can chain other tools like i.e. `awk` to have what you need and as you need. Example shell script doing that, say `clone.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash

set -e

DST=`echo $1 | awk 'i=index($0,":") {print substr($0,i+1,length($0)-i-4)}'`
mkdir -p "${DST}" && git clone $1 "${DST}"
```

then (after obvious `chmod`):

```
./clone.sh git@github.com:scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git
```

and you good.

Comment: right, I know that.  What I was wondering is if this can be done without needing to manually create the directories or write a script and alias `git clone`.

Comment: no, but you can easily write short bash script to extract the dir, generate, create, guess or make target dir as you like. there's no point for this type of logic to be built-in really

Answer (score 0):

One tool that is very useful to organize and maintain repositories updated is mr (http://myrepos.branchable.com/). See this blog post for details  http://odinodin.no/2013-11-23-multiple-repositories/

You need to create a configuration file where you indicate the location of your repo (a path, not necessarily created) and mr will create that path and clone your repo. It will also help you keep the many repos you have up to date.