# How to clone git repository in bash to created tree of folders

Tags: bash, git, clone, auto

I would like to clone all repositories to one place in tree without the need to change directory.

for example my main path to repositories is `/home/username/repositories/`

I would like to clone any repository using any of:

- git://server.com[:port]/username/repositoryname[.git]
- http[s]://[username:password@]server.com[:port]/username/repositoryname[.git]
- ssh://[username:password@]server.com[:port]/username/repositoryname[.git]

to main path but with some created subfolders:
/home/username/repositories/github.com/username/repositoryname/

Do you know any existing solution (script/application) which I can somehow use?

I have created some simple solution but not for all params/addresses:
https://pastebin.com/0J9gDfKe

Comment: Looks like you would have to write your own script :) I really doubt that there's some general tool doing exactly that :)

Comment: Adapt the script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555416/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+full+path